# How to get top selling item every month

Tags: mysql

I want to get top selling item/product for every month. I tried to using GROUP BY function, but my problem is how to get just 1 product in every month.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date), product, SUM(quantity)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date), product
```

Also, how to use `row_number() over` function in mysql? I think by using that I can get just 1 product per month?

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Comment: SO isn't (or isn't intended to be) a free, code-writing service.

Comment: We love that you're here and we want to see the code you're trying to fix so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select MONTHNAME(`date`),product,sum(quantity) qty
from tablename a
group by MONTHNAME(`date`),product
having max(qty) in (select sum(quantity) from tablename b where MONTHNAME(a.`date`)=MONTHNAME(b.`date`) and a.product=b.product)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        month, n, product, quantity
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(MONTHNAME(date) != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := MONTHNAME(date),
                MONTHNAME(date) AS month, product, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
            FROM  mytable
            GROUP BY
                MONTHNAME(date), product
            ORDER BY
                MONTHNAME(date) ASC,
                SUM(quantity) DESC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 1
    ORDER BY  month, n
```